# How to use pip with multiple instances of python

Tags: python, bash, pip

I recently installed python3 only to realize that mysql-python as well as many other modules were not well supported with it yet.  So I changed the path in my bashrc file to point to an installation of python 2.7.  The problem is that when I installed python 3 I also installed distribute and pip along with it.  I removed the pip and distribute files from the python3 bin directory and installed setuptools and pip using python 2.7 however now when I use the pip command to install django and mysql-python, I get a bash error python331/bin/pip No such file or directory.  It's still looking for pip in the python3 install.  How can I remedy this?

Thanks

Comment: You should have used virtualenv.

Comment: and seeing as I did not, any suggestions?

Comment: If I had a suggestion, it would be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I get a bash error `python331/bin/pip No such file or directory`.
>   It's still looking for pip in the python3 install. How can I remedy
>   this?

`bash`, by default, hashes the locations of commands to avoid searching `$PATH` each time, so if, when you execute...

```
$ type pip
```

...you get something like...

```
pip is hashed (python331/bin/pip)
```

...you just need to clear the hash table for `bash` with...

```
$ hash -r
```

...then it'll pick up the version in Python 2.7 the next time you try to run `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

Renamed the directory of where the python3 was installed, bash automatically looks for the next available python install python 2.7

Comment: I have ec2 instance where python2.6 and 2.7 are available but I want to use only python2.7 directory. It takes by default 2.6. How can I do this.