# python pip still looking for previous installation

Tags: python, homebrew

After experiencing [this](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17312) brew issue with sqlite3, I did

```
brew rm sqlite python python3
```

then

```
brew install python python3
```

This installed python2.7.5 as the default interpreter and as brew installs pip along with python, I thought I would be able to

```
pip install virtualenv
```

to install virtualenv for the new python2.7.5. However, I'm getting

```
-bash: /usr/local/share/python/pip: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How can I get around/fix this? Should I be creating a symlink between

```
/usr/local/share/python/pip --> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/bin/pip-2.7
```

Comment: Might just be a stale entry in the `bash` hashtable. Does `hash -r` fix the problem? See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363658/how-to-use-pip-with-multiple-instances-of-python/16364011#16364011).

Comment: hash -r doesn't fix it. when I do 'type pip', I get pip is hashed (/usr/local/share/python/pip)

Comment: Well, in this case it would be the wrong `python`, so `type python` would be more appropriate. If that points to the correct binary, maybe it's just the first `#!` line in `/usr/local/share/python/pip` which is pointing to a bogus copy of Python for some reason.

Comment: That would make more sense. `/usr/local/share/python/pip` as well as `/usr/local/share/python/virtualenv` were both pointing to the old python. Changing to the new version has fixed it. If you submit your comment above as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds like your `/usr/local/share/python/pip` is pointing to the wrong version of Python. Check the first line of that file, and if it looks like...

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python
```

...then you'll need to change it to point to the correct version of Python.

Answer (score 4):

The python3 homebrew package installs pip as pip3. You can even install multiple versions of python 3, e.g. python 3.2 and 3.3 and each will get linked as pip-3.3 and pip-3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I would install Python 2.7 form the [project's page](http://www.python.org/getit/), and later use `pip` to install all other packages from within virtualenv. It works for me.

Comment: I see from the [homebrew git page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula)  that the only versions available are 2.7.5 and 3. I don't mind having an updated version of 2.7.x as I can just recreate virtualenvs. I just need the current python to be 2.7.5

Comment: Can't you install it from python page, and not from homebrew? I have Mac OS and I did it like that

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a cluster and cannot (and should not) access the root directory: `/usr/local/share/python/pip`, you should look in your home directory instead: `$HOME/.local/bin/pip`.  Check that the proper python location is referenced there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on Windows 10 after uninstalling a 32-bit version of python and installing a 64-bit version.

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using `'"c:\users\yourname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pandas': The system cannot find the file specified.`

I found out the Path System Environment variables didn't update.

I had to change the values from:

```
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
```

to:

```
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
```

You can find them by going to:

System Properties > Advanced Tab>Environment Variables >
System Variables box at the bottom > Click 'Path' Variable>Click Edit... >

Click the two paths listed above and click Edit to change them to match the correct version

Note: You may need to restart your IDE or Terminal for this change to take effect.