# How to link home brew python version and set it as default

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I just switched from MacPorts to HomeBrew. After installing all the required XCode versions and other software I tried installing python using homebrew: I think it successfully installed, but when I do `which python` it still shows me 2.7.3 which I think is the version shipped with Mountain Lion.

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python

python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

so I tried to install again

```
brew install python --framework --universal
Warning: python-2.7.5 already installed, it's just not linked
```

But it says python 2.7.5 already install and not linked, I tried to do `brew link python`

That led me to following message so, I have no idea what I should be doing:

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5... Warning: Could not link python. Unlinking...

```
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/bin/smtpd2.py
Target /usr/local/bin/smtpd2.py already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of several others. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354207/how-to-symlink-python-in-homebrew) seems to have the best solution. Or maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633590/python-pip-still-looking-for-previous-installation).

Comment: OK, and what happens when you execute those commands?

Answer (score 63):

After installing python3 with `brew install python3`
I was getting the error:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

After typing `brew link python3` the error was:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

To solve the problem:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/Frameworks
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
brew link python3
```

After this, I could open python3 by typing `python3`

(From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/20985)

Comment: you don't have to `chown -R` /usr/local, fyi... posting answer below

Comment: Chaim Eliyah: probably. But, the code snippet is from the official homebrew repository.

Answer (score 14):

In the Terminal, type:

```
brew link python
```

Comment: nope, I get `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework`

Comment: `brew link --overwrite python@3.10` did the trick for me

Answer (score 12):

If you used

```
brew install python
```

before 'unlink'
you got

```
brew info python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11

python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

so do

```
brew unlink python && brew link python
```

and open a new terminal shell

```
python -V
Python 2.7.11
```

Comment: Like @eric-guo wrote: you need `--force`, so `brew unlink python && brew link python2 --force`.

Answer (score 12):

For those looking for a version re-link using **brew**, I've found this command useful:

```
brew unlink python@3.9 && brew link python@3.10
```

It is possible that some errors appear, like:

```
Error: Could not symlink bin/pip3
Target /usr/local/bin/pip3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/pip3'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python@3.10

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python@3.10
```

So following brew advice and running:

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/pip3'
brew link --overwrite python@3.10
```

Just worked for me. To check if symlinks are ok, run: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*`, you should see something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/bin/python3-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.10 -> ../Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/bin/python3.10
/usr/local/bin/python3.10-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.2/bin/python3.10-config
```

Comment: With `python@3.9` (3.9.18) brew fails to create the links for `/usr/local/bin/python3`, `/usr/local/bin/python3-config` and `/usr/local/bin/pip3` which is inconvenient, and inconsistent at the very least.

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to be precise with which version you want to link with the command `brew link python` like:

```
brew link python 3
```

It will give you an error like that:

> ```
> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2... 
> Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3-3.5
> Target /usr/local/bin/2to3-3.5
> already exists.
> ```

You may want to remove it:

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.5'
```

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
brew link --overwrite python3
```

To list all files that would be deleted:

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run python3
```

but you have to copy/paste the command to force the link which is:

```
brew link --overwrite python3
```

I think that you must have the version (the newer) installed.

Answer (score 6):

On OS X High Sierra, I had to do this:

```
sudo install -d -o $(whoami) -g admin /usr/local/Frameworks
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python
brew install python
python --version # should work, returns 2.7, which is a Python thing (it's weird, but ok)
```

credit to https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/7732946#gistcomment-2235469

I think it's better than recursively chowning the /usr/local dir, but that may solve other problems ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can follow these steps.

```
$ python3 --version  
$ brew unlink python@2
$ brew link python3   
$ python3 --version
```

[image: All steps]

Answer (score 2):

brew switch to python3 by default, so if you want to still set python2 as default bin python, running:

```
brew unlink python && brew link python2 --force
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend playing around with the symlinks, it's not just to where `python` points, its the entire env around it as well that maybe mixing version

I would do this:

```
$ brew install pyenv
$ pyenv install 3.7.3
$ pyenv global 3.7.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for upgrading Python 2.7.10 to Python 2.7.11 on Mac OS X El Capitan . On Terminal type:

```
brew unlink python
```

After that type on Terminal

```
brew install python
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with me is that I have so many different versions of python, so it opens up a different python3.7 even after I did brew link. I did the following additional steps to make it default **after linking**

First, open up the document setting up the path of python

```
 nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then something like this shows up:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

The thing here is that my Python for brew framework is not in the **Library** Folder!! So I changed the framework for python 3.7, which looks like follows in my system

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Change and save the file. **Restart** the computer, and typing in `python3.7`, I get the python I installed for brew.

Not sure if my case is applicable to everyone, but worth a try. Not sure if the framework path is the same for everyone, please made sure before trying out.

Answer (score -2):

I use these commands to solve it.

```
mkdir /usr/local/lib
mkdir /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
brew link python
```