# Install OpenCV on Mac - VirtualEnv (Updated bash_profile and pip error)

Tags: macos, opencv, pip, homebrew, bash

I'm trying to install OpenCV on my Mac (OS X 10.11.3) using [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) tutorial because it uses a VirtualEnv, which is a way to ensure consistency in development.

I skipped Steps 1&2 since I already have Xcode and Homebrew.  Step 3 worked well (after updating `~/.bash_profile` as instructed):

```
User:~ user$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
User:~ user$ source ~/.bash_profile
User:~ user$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
User:~ user$
```

The trouble is in Step 4:

```
User:~ user$ pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
User:~ user$
```

This is probably because I'm in the local bin due to adding this to `~/.bash_profile` from Step 3:

```
# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This basically means I can't access pip from that location, but when I try to install it locally (with the above lines added in `~/.bash_profile`), it says:

```
User:~ user$ brew install pip
Error: No available formula with the name "pip" 
Homebrew provides pip via: `brew install python`. However you will then
have two Pythons installed on your Mac, so alternatively you can install
pip via the instructions at:

  https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/#install-pip
User:~ user$
```

How can I access pip with my updated `~/.bash_profile` from Step 3?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem.

I was getting the same errors as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340871/how-to-link-home-brew-python-version-and-set-it-as-default) stackoverflow question, so I ran the recommended

```
brew link python
```

which encountered the same errors as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354207/how-to-symlink-python-in-homebrew) stackoverflow question, so I ran the recommended

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

which seemed to correct the problem and allows me to run pip while accessing Homebrew packages first.