# catalina 10.51.1 python3 w brew or xcode-select

Tags: python, terminal, macos-catalina

I installed python3 from terminal with xcode method. Then realized I could have just used homebrew. When I run python3 the version I have installed is 3.7.3. When I installed brew it supposedly installed the latest which is 3.7.5.
So how do I make sure I only have 3.7.5 installed? I don't want 2 versions of 3. Am I missing something?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I hope this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340871/how-to-link-home-brew-python-version-and-set-it-as-default

Comment: hmm thanks a lotta info there.. I wanna nail the correct one (fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the machine fixed it. Running "python" in terminal now runs 3.7.5
¯_(ツ)_/¯